# How to approach a mathematical proof about the uniqueness of solution of a diophantine equation

Tags: proof-writing, systems-of-equations

I need some guidance on how I would go about approaching a mathematical proof

I need to prove that $x^2 = y^2 + 41$ has a unique solution where $x$ and $y$ are both non-negative integers.

What I have deduced and tried so far.

1. I understand that $41$ is a prime number so that could be of importance
2. I attempted to solve this equation mathematically but once again with no luck

What/where should I look into next any hints on what my next approach should be?

**Note:** I do not want the answer, but only some guidance.

Answer (score 4):

Make it $ x^2-y^2 = 41 $

This gives $ (x-y) \times (x+y) = 1 \times 41 $

Use Prime Number to get the Solution.

This will work.